# Criteria entries by date field

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, datetime, plugin-elementapi

I want to get only entries with a specific date. I created a date field `customDateField`. It has the following code:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('orders').customDateField('2016-04-14') %}
```

but this not work. How it will look in php?

In element api plugin i was code:

```
'endpoints' => [
    'orders.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'orders',
            'date' => '>='.craft()->request->getPost('date')
        ],
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'id' => $entry->id,
            ];
        },
    ],
]
```

but it only shows a larger date of entries, need to write `'date->format("Y-m-d")'`

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you're getting caught out by querying a specific time of day. I think if you don't include the time it would presume '00:00'. What you want is to find any entries with the `customDateField` value between midnight and 23:59.

```
{% set myDateString = '2016-04-01' %}
{% set myDateStart = myDateString | date_modify('00:00') | date('Y-m-d H:i') %}
{% set myDateEnd = myDateString | date_modify('23:59')  | date('Y-m-d H:i') %}

{% set entries = craft.entries.section('orders').customDateField('and', '>= ' ~ myDateStart, '<= ' ~ myDateEnd) %}
```

Comment: there between is not necessary

Comment: Although this code is also useful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra php code to do that.

The search function probably does the job for you.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('orders').search('2016-04-14') %}
{% for entry in entries %}
  <h1>{{entry.title}} - {{entry.customDateField}}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: php for the need to place the code in the element api plugin